# Stopping test runner after first failing test

Tags: junit, junit5, junit-runner

We have created a custom test runner for Junit 5. However, we would like to stop this runner after the first failing test. I've looked into Extensions, but these all work with `ExtensionContext` which does not seem to provide any way to stop the runner.

How can I stop the runner after a failed test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For various reasons this is currently not supported by the junit-platform. Have a look at this issue: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1729

So the only option you have is to use `System.exit()`. Be prepared, though, to run into misbehaving IDEs and build tools.